# Can not use add with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I just did poetry init (and did not install anything)

After that if I do

```
poetry add pandas

'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'strict'
```

What might be the problem and how can I solve it.
(I read a question similar to this but did not understand the reason of the problem. Please don't say just "read the answer")

Comment: How do your `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` look like?

Comment: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7936

Answer (score 0):

with python 3.11, with poetry 1.7.1,in the same situation, with the command: `poetry add pandas`, I obtain:

```
Creating virtualenv bb-fnQ1yfAQ-py3.11 in /home/anclarma/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Using version ^2.1.4 for pandas

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ac/dea2939dfc3c591a2494121669455fd7Resolving dependencies... (1.2s)

Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing six (1.16.0)
  • Installing numpy (1.26.2)
  • Installing python-dateutil (2.8.2)
  • Installing pytz (2023.3.post1)
  • Installing tzdata (2023.3)
  • Installing pandas (2.1.4)

Writing lock file
```

can you be more precise?